# Menu Characters in Java

Tags: java, string, menu, char, user-input

I'm new to programming in Java, and have been having problems understanding how to take user input and translate it into something that my program would understand. I'm trying in this program to input in a character from the user, and have the program take it and use it in the switch statement. Would someone please be kind enough to tell me what keyword or technique I would use to input a character, or translate a string into a character for my program without it being really convoluted? I appreciate your help, and thank you in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.util.Scanner;
public class VendingMachine;
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
      int selection=0;
      int x=0;
      float origItemNum = 15;
      float origDebitBal = 15;
      double balanceDebit;
      double balanceItemNum;
      double items = 0;
      char choice = 0;

      //initialize variables


      boolean validSelection;
      System.out.print("\nInitial Account Settings:");
      System.out.print("\nUnused Item Capacity: 15");
      System.out.print("\nCost (so far) this month: $15");
      balanceDebit=origDebitBal;
      balanceItemNum = origItemNum;

      while(x==0)
      {
         System.out.print("\nMenu:"); 
         System.out.print("\nB (show Bill and starts new month)");  
         System.out.print("\nU (show Unused capacity for the current month)"); 
         System.out.print("\nC (Consume vending items now -- " +
               "purchase candy bar, bag of chips, etc.)"); 
         System.out.print("\nA (buy Additional items for current month)"); 
         System.out.print("\nQ (show bill and Quit)"); 
         String strUserAnswer;
         String strQuestion;
         String choiceVerify;
         Scanner input_stream = new Scanner(System.in);
         strQuestion = new String("What choice would you like? Please" +
               "enter in either option A, B, U, C- or enter E to quit. ");
         strUserAnswer = input_stream.nextLine();
         choice = (char) Integer.parseInt(strUserAnswer);
         choiceVerify = ("You chose choice: ");
         System.out.print(strUserAnswer);
         input_stream.close();
         switch (selection)
         {
         case 'b':
         case 'B': 
            System.out.print("\n\nClosing bill for month:");
         //   System.out.print("\nUnused items (lost):" );
         //   System.out.print(balanceItemNum);
          //  System.out.print("\nFinal amount due immediately: $" );
          //  System.out.print(balanceDebit);
           // System.out.print("\nStarting new month ...Available items: 15");
           // balanceItemNum = 15;
           // balanceDebit = 15;
            break;

         case 'u':
         case 'U':
            System.out.print("\nUnused capacity of items you can use: " );
           // System.out.print(balanceItemNum);
           // System.out.print("\nYour debit balance: $" );
           // System.out.print(balanceDebit);
            break;

         case 'c':
         case 'C':
            System.out.print("\nNumber of items you want to purchase:");
          //  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            //items = input.nextDouble();
            //balanceItemNum = balanceItemNum-items;
           // balanceDebit = balanceDebit - items;
           // System.out.print("\nAvailable Items: " );
           // System.out.print(balanceItemNum);
            break;

         case 'a':
         case 'A': 
            String numberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\nAdditional " +
                  "items purchase in sets of 10 (1-3):");
           // double number = Double.parseDouble(numberString);
            //      while (number == 1 || number == 2 || number == 3)
           // number = number * 11;
           // balanceItemNum = balanceItemNum + number;
           // balanceDebit = balanceDebit + number;
            break;

         case 'e':
         case 'E':
            System.out.print("\nYour debit balance: $" );
           // System.out.print(balanceDebit);
            break;
         }
      }

      while (choice != 'e' && choice != 'E');
      System.out.print("\nError: Please enter in either B, U, C, A or Q.");
      return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strUserAnswer = input_stream.nextLine();
char c = strUserAnswer.charAt(0);
```

and then switch on c

Also, you will run into a problem by calling `input_stream.close();` inside of your while loop. It must be on the outside of the loop in order for you to read more the once (you can't read anything in with a closed Scanner).

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line

```
choice = (char) Integer.parseInt(strUserAnswer);
```

so it looks like this

```
choice = strUserAnswer.charAt(0);
```

With this change, using `charAt(0)` you get the character in position 0 (the first one) of what the user enters, and then saving it in a variable named choice.

and then change the variable **selection** to **choice** in this part

```
switch(selection){
    //all of your code
}
```

So it would look like this

```
switch(choice){ 
    //all of your code
}
```

So the switch will use the variable where you stored the used input before.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good start, but there are some things that you should try and improve. You can reduce the length and significantly improve readability of your code by doing things like this:

```
String choiceVerify;
choiceVerify = ("You chose choice: ");
```

becomes

```
String choiceVerifyc = "You chose choice: ";
```

And this:

```
String strUserAnswer;
strUserAnswer = input_stream.nextLine();
```

becomes:

```
String strUserAnswer = input_stream.nextLine();
```

By shortening and removing unncessecary parts of your code you make it much easier for people trying to help you here on StackOverflow.

Good luck with your coding!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate you taking the time to go over my code, answer my question, and the additional pointers on improving the readability of my code/etiquette. Thank you again!